# Checking date_start and date_end

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-validation

I have a start date and a end date in a form...

[image]

In my method `rules` I have this:

```php
    public function rules()
    {
            return [
                //
                'date_revision_start' => 'after:2009-01-01|before:2023-01-01',
                'date_revision_end' => 'after:2009-01-01|before:2023-01-01'
             ];
    }
```

The end date cannot be before the start date.Where should I make the condition?
In the Controller ?

```php
    if ($this->request->get('date_revision_start') < $this->request->get('date_revision_end')) 
    {
               return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                    ->with('error', 'The end date cannot be before the start date!');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no need to check condition if you are using validation

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
        'date_revision_start' => 'after:2009-01-01|before:2023-01-01',
        'date_revision_end' => 'after:date_revision_start|before:2023-01-01'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Karan. ^^

Comment: Glad to help you... @user11124425

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and do something like this:

```php
if (Carbon::parse($request->get('date_revision_start')->greaterThan(Carbon::parse($this->request->get('date_revision_end')))) {
    return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                ->with('error', 'The end date cannot be before the start date!');
}
```

If you using like this you can  do this at start of your controller.

Or you can use validation:

```php
public function rules() {
        return [
            'date_revision_end' => 'date|after:date_revision_start|before:2023-01-01'
         ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'date_revision_start' => 'after:2009-01-01|before_or_equal:2023-01-01',
            'date_revision_end' => 'after:2009-01-01|after_or_equal:2023-01-01'
         ];
}
```